# Как отформатировать число в JS и вывести в Pug?

Tags: javascript, jade, pug

Передаю в вид объект:

```
offers
{
    "id":129,
    "logourl":"129.png",
    "mincreditsum":7000,
    "maxcreditsum":200000"
}
```

Хочу `mincreditsum` и `maxcreditsum` отформатировать и привести к виду `7 000` и `200 000`. Нашел такую регулярку:

```
replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+([^\d]|$))/g, '$1 ')
```

Вывожу сейчас в цикле так:

```
each offer,index in offers_arr
    span.minsumm !{offer.mincreditsum}
    span.maxsumm !{offer.maxcreditsum}
```

Как можно применить регулярко? Сейчас объявил функцию:

```
script.
var myFunc = function (a) {
    return a.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+([^\d]|$))/g, '$1 ');
}
```

И в цикле её вызываю:

```
each offer,index in offers_arr
 span#summin!= myFunc(offer.mincreditsum)
```

Но выдает ошибку:

> Call to undefined function myFunc()

Как будет правильно?

Comment: По всей видимости ваша функция не видна. Взгляните на этот ответ: [Jade: load external javascript and call function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33271556/5275890).

Comment: @DenisBubnov Благодарю за ответ,но не могли бы поподробнее объяснить,я объявил эту функцию в том же файле,только выше.Код сейчас выглядит так https://pastebin.com/8QxMfW31

Comment: Из ошибки я увидел, что вы пытаетесь обратиться к неопределенной функции. Но если вы ее объявили, значит она не видна в том месте, где вы ее вызываете. Поэтому я поискал что-то наподобии загрузики внешнего `JavaScript` и вызова функции в `Jade`. Нашел тот ответ, что привел в комментарии выше, который в принципе связан с `JavaScript`, `node.js`, `Pug` и `Jade` и дал вам ссылку. Увы, большим я помочь не могу, так как воспроизвести данный пример не могу :(

Comment: @DenisBubnov окей,все равно благодарю,буду шаманить)